# Get ID of newly created Folder in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As part of a Google Apps Script project, I'm trying to move the active spreadsheet and several uploaded files to a new folder that is created within a shared directory.

I have been able to create the new folder with:

```
DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolder).createFolder(rename);
```

But to be able to move the files where I need to know the ID of the folder that's just been created.

The rest of the code works ok - if I just put in a string as another folders ID everything gets moved. I'm just stuck on actually finding that new folder ID.

Any ideas?

ta

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can retrieve folder ID using "getId()". For example, your code can be written as follows.

```
var id = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolder).createFolder(rename).getId();
```

If the folder name is only one on Drive, you can retrieve folder ID from folder name like below.

```
var id = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(rename).next().getId();
```