# Moving a folder (with its contents) with DriveApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

DriveApp does not have a "move"-function (as of today). How can I move this folder (with all its contents as it is)?

I wish to move the source_folder (which currently resides in parent_folder)

```
var source_Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(source_id);
var parent_Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parent_id);
```

and put it inside target_folder:

```
var target_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(target_id);
```

*I already have source_id,parent_id and target_id*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implement a folder move function in Google Dirve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393932/implement-a-folder-move-function-in-google-dirve)

Comment: That question mentioned both SDK and API, so I feel my question is more straight to the case (also the other question have recieved negative comments - so I dont know if its correct to mark this as duplicate). But the answer in that link is a good answer, so I will add the link to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I looked around a bit and there is similar questions/answer to this problem. I made this to (hopefully) make it easy for others with the same problem.

> "Folders" in Google Drive work pretty much the same way as "Labels" in
>   Gmail.

You may add a folder multiple places in Google Drive. It will still be only one folder (not a copy) so its contents are available from all the places where you added the folder.

> To *simulate* moving the source_folder, you
>   can:

1) first add the source_folder to the target_folder

```
target_folder.addFolder(source_folder);
```

2) remove the source_folder from its parent.

```
parent_folder.removeFolder(source_folder);
```

> full example code: (note: you need the folder ID's)

```
function move_folder() { // id looks like this: 1XqH79csKkPMvTsCxMUzkkpURETKHJ
   var source_id = "[insert_folder_id]"; // folder you wish to move
   var parent_id = "[insert_folder_id]"; // where the folder is currently
   var target_id = "[insert_folder_id]"; // where you want to put the folder

   var source_Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(source_id);
   var parent_Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parent_id);
   var target_Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(target_id);

   target_folder.addFolder(source_folder);    // source_folder now 2 places
   parent_folder.removeFolder(source_folder); // cleanup
 }
```

> how to get folder_id.

- right-clicking on a folder and getting a shareable link. (the random-looking string after *id=*)
- [Get ID of newly created Folder in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079656/get-id-of-newly-created-folder-in-google-apps-script)
- parent folder: [DriveApp parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879647/driveapp-parent-folder)

a good answer is also found here: [Implement a folder move function in Google Dirve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393932/implement-a-folder-move-function-in-google-dirve)